# How to Select Full Row in Repeater in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi Experts
How to Select Full Row in Repeater Control in asp.net
I Have Right the following code

```
function SetSelectedModuleIdRow(rowId, objRepeater) {
            var rows = document.getElementById(objRepeater).getElementsByTagName("TR");
            for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                cells = rows[j].getElementsByTagName("TD");
                for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
                }
            }
            var row = parseInt(rowId) + 1;
            arrCol = rows[row].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var j = 0; j < arrCol.length; j++) {
                arrCol[j].style.background = '#808080 ';
            }
        }
```

on ItemDatabound call this function.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to:

[Highlight a row in repeater control in ItemCommand event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/3c140248-6f92-4853-97ae-6b91df959885/)

[How can i highlight a selected row in a Repeater Control](http://forums.asp.net/t/1479134.aspx/1)

[Highlight Row on MouseOver in Repeater Control](http://yasserzaid.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/highlight-row-on-mouseover-in-repeater-control/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function Select(obj) {
  obj.className = 'selected';
  var tbl = document.getElementById("table1")
  var firstRow = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
  var oldRow = tbl.rows[firstRow.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value];
  if (oldRow != null) {
     oldRow.className = '';
  }
  firstRow.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = obj.rowIndex;
}
```

In repeater's `tr` you put this:

```
<tr style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Select(this);">
```

And in the `<scipt>` tag, put:

```
.selected
{
   background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean in the stylesheet for the last part?