# Highlight Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, repeater, highlight

I'm struggling with having my selected item highlighted. My code works, but it only highlight the selected item just once, and when the results are displayed, it went back un-highlighted.

Here are my codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeColor(elem){
            elem.style.backgroundColor = "#C9C9C9";
        }
</script>
```

...
...
...

```
<td onclick="changeColor(this)">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSkills" runat="server" 
        OnClick="showProjects" 
        PostBackUrl='<%# "NewUserSearch.aspx?name=" + Server.UrlEncode(Eval("staff_name").ToString()) %>'>
</td>
```

I hope this info is enough 
Any idea on how to edit my codes and highlight the selected item throughout? Instead of only being highlighted and back to un-highlighted state.

Comment: If you are posting back to the server then you are getting back an entirely new page. This means that any changes made with JavaScript on the client are completely gone. Maybe you could write some server side code to highlight the selected item.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!
Well, I've tried giving my td an id (which is now <td id="td1">)
the problem is, I don't know what to write on the aspx.cs page.
Any idea what the code is? or any webpage that I can reference to?

Comment: Is it possible to get a little more context on what you are trying to do? I've got a rough idea how to help you with your problem but some more details (and possibly some more of your code) would help.

Comment: Basically I got 2 repeater. One that display users, and one that display user's information

When I click on the user's name, the other repeater will display the user's information.
What I want to achieve is, when i click on the user's name, that particular row will be highlighted.

Right now, when I click on the user's name, the row will be highlighted. But when the results are out, the row went back to un-highlighted state. *Screen refreshes upon displaying results*

Any possible way to contact you? Through message or facebook?
Thanks alot!

Comment: It's definitely more complicated considering your item is wrapped in a repeater but I'll try to post a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I was going to try and cobble some code together for you, but you'll be better off with some code that's already out there (I write in VB not C#). Remember: Google Is Your Friend. This answer (which references other answers) may provide your best reference for selecting a specific row in the repeater:
   [How to Select Full Row in Repeater in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973643/how-to-select-full-row-in-repeater-in-asp-net)
   Or try this one:
   [repeater row highlight does not persist after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797919/repeater-row-highlight-does-not-persist-after-postback)
   This one looks promising too:
   http://forums.asp.net/t/1642414.aspx/1
2. You may want to use a FormView or DetailsView to display the user details.
3. If you have time and want to enhance your page, it would probably benefit from using AJAX (UpdatePanel) to refresh the user details. If you get that working, the javascript might be all you need, but you would also need to remove highlighting when you changed the selection.

Comment: Hey probackpacker, thanks for the link! it surely helps me alot!
I've referred to this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/3c140248-6f92-4853-97ae-6b91df959885/

I have a small problem now, which is to un-highlight the previous row. I did a count, loop, to it but it's still highlighted.
Any idea how can I approach my problem now?
Sorry for the trouble. I'm quite new to coding

Comment: In the item command code you might want to get the `Repeater`, as the item's naming container, and loop through all the other `repeaterItems` in the `repeater` and remove the backcolor.